# scrollIntoView smooth scrolling goes way more down as it should in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, autoscroll

after upgrade from Angular 8 to Angular 9 I encountered a problem that the smooth scrolling causes the scrolling go way more down as it should, so that the element is not even in the view, but way more up. This only happens when I the **route is changed**, if the route remains the same - the smooth scrolling is Ok.

Implementation:
I created a directive for scrolling:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollToSelected]'
})
export class ScrollToSelectedDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('scrollToSelected') scrollToClass: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains(this.scrollToClass)) {
      this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center', behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }
```

on the template I conditionally append the selected class:

```
<div class="order-job-operation-component"
     *ngIf="operation$ | async as operation"
     [scrollToSelected]="'selected'"
     [class.selected]="operation.isSelected">
```

Once I delete the smooth behavior - it works well again.

"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "9.0.2",
"@angular/cdk": "9.0.1",
"@angular/common": "9.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "9.0.2",
"@angular/core": "9.0.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.29",
"@angular/forms": "9.0.2",
"@angular/localize": "9.0.2",
"@angular/material": "9.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.2",
"@angular/router": "9.0.2",

"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.9",
"@angular/cli": "9.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.2",

Answer (score 0):

try this `.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.